# C with postgresql

Tags: c, windows, postgresql

I'd like to write (on windows) a program in C that connects with postgres database.
First, i had in the 3 line

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
```

but then i got an error

```
... main.c|3|fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

so i changed 3 line to

```
#include "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/include/libpq-fe.h"
```

but i still get an error

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lpq-fe.h|
```

any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/include/libpq-fe.h"
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  PGresult *result;
  PGconn   *conn;

  conn = PQconnectdb("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb 
          user=postgres password=mypassword");

  if(PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_OK) {
    printf("connection made\n");
  }
  else
    printf("connection failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));

  PQfinish(conn);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-build.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the path to the include directive, that is you stick with

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
```

You specify the path to the file as *include directory* to the compiler.

How you do that depends on the compiler you are using.

With Microsoft Visual C, you would invoke `cl` with

```
cl /I C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/include ...
```

With MinGW and `gcc`, you would write

```
gcc -L C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/include ...
```

Comment: in this case i use code blocks and i added to compiler options -L "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/include"
but i still get an error 
    ld.exe||cannot find C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include: Permission denied|

Comment: There you have the answer: *permission denied*. You must change the file and directory permissions so that the user who runs the compiler has permission to read the header files.